# Tabindex 0 on focusable element (button)

Tags: accessibility, tabindex

I've noticed the following pattern on several occasions in a code base I'm currently working on:

```
<button tabindex="0">A button</button>
<ul tabindex="-1">...
```

Of course, `tabindex="-1"` on the `ul` prevents focus, but what's the point of setting `tabindex=0` on a button? Isn't this element already focusable by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both uses of `tabindex` are superfluous.  The <button> doesn't need it to receive focus and the <ul> doesn't need it to prevent focus.  Looks like a rookie wrote that code.

Comment: Agreed - but: the tabindex="-1" basically says: "not focusable with tab, but JavaScript (or other script) can focus this."

Comment: @TimB, true, and there are cases where you should use `tabindex="-1"` but in general, you do not want to place the focus (programmatically via javascript) on an element that is not actionable/interactive.  That is confusing for screen reader users.  The focus was moved to an element but they can't select it.  Skip links (WCAG 2.4.1 Bypass Blocks) are an exception.  If the screen reader user or keyboard user selects a skip link, then focus is often moved to a heading or other <main> element.

Comment: Agreed. But usually, unless you don't do a custom implementation, you won't have to use tabindex="-1" on skip link target, as it works out of the box for most browsers. An exception is IE.

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate some more on the use of tabindex and what this means in this context:

Tabindex="0" means: Focusable with tab key and from script (using `element.focus()`), and inserted into the natural taborder (aka the order logically following the DOM). As this is the default behaviour of buttons, you can ditch `<button tabindex="0">` as nonsense and bloatcode.

Tabindex greater than 0 assigns a custom taborder. So, if you say `<button tabindex="1">`, the button will always get focused first when using tab, regardless of the DOM-structure. This method is discouraged.

Tabindex="-1" says you can't focus it using tab, but the JavaScript `element.focus()` function will work. On an `ul` this only makes sense if you want to focus it from script at some point. Else this is bloatcode as well, and also assigns an unintended role.